# Why would a portion of my URI be replaced with the text '<DELIMITER>' in a Logic App definition?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App which makes a `GET` call to an API app. Building the URI is a little complex. The JSON definition looks like this:

```
"uri": "https://my-api-staging.azurewebsites.net/authorize/@{encodeURIComponent('R')}/@{encodeURIComponent(body('WorkflowStepArgument')?['Properties']['WorkflowOwnerRole'])},@{encodeURIComponent(body('WorkflowStepArgument')?['Properties']['WorkflowOwnerAccount'])},@{encodeURIComponent(body('WorkflowStepArgument')?['Properties']['WorkflowOwner'])}/@{encodeURIComponent(substring(body('WorkflowStepArgument')?['Payload']['Resources']['Input'],0,lastIndexOf(body('WorkflowStepArgument')?['Payload']['Resources']['Input'], '/')))}"
```

This works, and the Logic App runs correctly, but if I switch from Code View to Design in VS 2017 (extended with Azure Logic Apps Tools for VS v.1.0), then with no other interaction on my part, this URI is replaced with:

```
 "uri": "https://my-api-staging.azurewebsites.net/authorize/@{encodeURIComponent('R')}/<DELIMITER>,<DELIMITER>,<DELIMITER>/@{encodeURIComponent(body('WorkflowStepArgument')?['Properties']['WorkflowOwnerRole'])}"
```

Is this just a bug in the tooling, or is there something wrong with the way I am constructing the URI?

And is there any fix or workaround (it's annoying not to be able to use Design view to verify my Logic App syntax before hitting Publish)?

Comment: have you tried from the portal, it could be an issue on the vs tooling